# Char a baby sheep?

Tags: accent, australian-english

I was watching a video called "Amnesia day" by Juice Media and I heard this phrase:

> Come on straya! Crack a tinnie! Char a baby sheep! Stick a flag on your car! Or on your knob!

I was feeling pretty confident about my English until I heard these sentences. Can someone explain what do they mean? I only understood the flag part.

Note: They are Australian so it probably has to do with something from Australian accent and culture.

Comment: Don't let this affect your confidence - the vast majority of non-Australasian native English speakers also struggle with "Strine," which is an Australian slang term for Australian slang. I can guess all of these, but this whole quote is deliberately difficult for non-Australians. Although "knob" is also British slang.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

**Come on straya** - ‘straya’ is phonetically-spelled way of the abbreviation of Australia. Just imagine you’re drunk and say it.

**Crack a tinnie** - Crack open a tin of beer - crack could be considered onomatopoeic

**Char a baby sheep** - Cook some lamb, probably on the barbecue since char implies fire and Australia is stereotypically associated with barbecuing.

**Stick a flag on your car or on your knob** - Deliberate over exaggeration to encourage large shows of patriotism.

Comment: I'm baffled by "Stick a flag on your... knob."  I'm in the U.S., and I'm not familiar with flags being stuck on door knobs or any other kind of knob.

Comment: @WayneConrad I’d lower your mind toward the gutter and think of a piece of male anatomy one could metaphorically reference as a flag pole :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Now I understand why you did not elaborate on that in your answer.  Please forget I asked. :)

Comment: the video shows a durex condom with an Australian flag on it https://youtu.be/BaA0hZ406YY?t=64

Comment: @hojusaram A condom with a national flag on it is for those who think being figuratively screwed by their country just isn't enough.